# How many solutions are possible to the equation $a^x-b^y=c$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

If $a,b,c\in \mathbb Z$ are known and $a>b>1,(a,b)=1$, how many integer solutions are possible to the equation $$a^x-b^y=c~?\tag1$$ 
Can $(1)$ has more than $4$ integer solutions ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are at most two solutions in positive integers $x$ and $y$, due to some guy (Canadian J. Math 2001).``On some exponential equations of S. S. Pillai)''.

Comment: Thanks, I remember it has at most two solutions, but not surely.